# Get duplicate value when change Picklist Value API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

So I make a huge blunder by changing the API Name of Picklist Value. First I change the API Name from "cancelled" to "Cancelled". But then I realise everywhere in the Flows Builder still use the previous API Name ("cancelled"). When I realise that and try to change back to the original API Name, I get "Duplicate API Name" error message:

[image: Error Message]

Can you help me to retrieve my original API name ("cancelled")?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps.  First, change it to something that doesn't match case-insensitively, e.g. from "Cancelled" to "Canceled". Then change it from "Canceled" to "cancelled".

(Your screenshot actually has "canceled" rather than "cancelled" so confirm which spelling is preferred.)